# Can I hide data on the table that has a specific or special values like zero? PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Problem**: I need to hide the data **BUT** not to delete it from the database that has a value or amount of zero or none value. Is there any possibilities to achieve this problem?

I just need to remove it from the bootstrap table

here is what my table looks like right now.

```
--------------------------------------
|  id  |  amount  |  name  |  price  |
|  1   |  3000    |  John  |  200    |
|  2   |  0       |  John  |  100    |
|  3   |  0       |  John  |  200    |
|  4   |  3000    |  Pat   |  400    |
--------------------------------------
```

The problem is there is the value of zero that should not be seen on my table, can that be solved by hiding or removing it?

**To put it simply the table must be look like this**

```
    --------------------------------------
    |  id  |  amount  |  name  |  price  |
    |  1   |  3000    |  John  |  200    |
    |------------------------------------
    |  4   |  3000    |  Pat   |  400    |
    --------------------------------------
```

**Here is my code**

```
<?php 

  //Fetch data
  $host = "local";
  $username = "name";
  $password = "";
  $database = "dbname";


  try {
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database",$username,$password);
    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

    $query = "SELECT * FROM  cabinqr_logs";

    $data = $connect->query($query);
 ?>

  <?php foreach($data as $row) 
                    {?>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><?php echo $row["passenger"] ?></th>
                        <td><?php echo $row["flight_no"] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row["amount"] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row["date_time"] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row["crew_name"] ?></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <?php 
                     }
                     } 
                        catch (PDOException $error) 
                        {
                          $error->getMessage();
                        }

                    ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to include a WHERE clause which says only to select rows with a value greater than zero in them...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  cabinqr_logs WHERE amount > 0";
```

Comment: never knew it can be that easy. thanks new learning again in php from oyu

Comment: ill mark it as an answer but can u wait for 11 mins? it says i can mark is as an answer in 11 minutes

Comment: can I ask another favor, from that part which has an amount of 6000 and 6000? how can I ADD it to total my amount? thank you

Comment: Probably easiest to keep a running total of the amount for each row and output it at the end